# Is there a way to get the Bundle ID at runtime?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is there a way to get the Bundle ID from Info.plist at runtime? Something like [[UIApplication sharedApplication] bundleIdentifier] would be great.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```